# Javascript Masonry not working with created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have created a page that uses a script to create divs with images inside of them and I append the image source using code. This page is intended to update a user's account with any uploaded images and display them. I have followed many of the tutorial guides and they all lead me to all of the images being in one column and overlapping. I pretty much used the code from : http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/bdgRzg and it doesn't work. Can someone direct me in the right direction as to what I did wrong?

HTML Code

```
<div class="tab-content" id="photos">
                    <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
                    <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
allImgs = document.getElementById("photos").getElementsByTagName("img");


//Create Elements For Each Image
for(i = 0; i<photoArr.length;i++)
{
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "entries row grid";
        document.getElementsByClassName("grid")[0].appendChild(div);
    }

    //<div class="entry one-third">
    div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "entry one-third grid-item";
    div.appendChild(div1);

    /* <figure>
            <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="" />
            <figcaption><a href="recipe.html"><i class="ico i-view"></i> <span>View recipe</span></a></figcaption>
        </figure>
    */
    fig = document.createElement("figure");
    div1.appendChild(fig);
    img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = photoArr[i];
    fig.appendChild(img);
    figcap = document.createElement("figcaption");
    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = "recipe.html";
    figcap.appendChild(link);
    iElement = document.createElement("i");
    iElement.className = "ico i-view";
    figcap.appendChild(iElement);
    span = document.createElement("span");
    t = document.createTextNode("View Recipe");                     
    span.appendChild(t);                                                                                                                                                
    figcap.appendChild(span);                   
    fig.appendChild(figcap);

    /*
    <div class="container">
        <h2><a href="recipe.html">Super easy blueberry cheesecake</a></h2> 
    */
    divCont = document.createElement("div");                                                                                                                                                                            
    divCont.className = "container";
    div1.appendChild(divCont);                                                                  
    h2 = document.createElement("h2");
    divCont.appendChild(h2);   
    link2 = document.createElement("a");
    link2.href = "recipe.html";
    h2.appendChild(link2);
    t2 = document.createTextNode("Yummy food");
    link2.appendChild(t2);
    /*

    /*div class="actions">
        <div>
        */
    divAct = document.createElement("div");
    divAct.className="actions";
    divCont.appendChild(divAct);
    div2 = document.createElement("div");
    divAct.appendChild(div2);

    /* <div class="difficulty"><i class="ico i-easy"></i><a href="#">easy</a></div> */
    div3 = document.createElement("div");
    div3.className="difficulty";
    div2.appendChild(div3);
    iElement2 = document.createElement("i");
    iElement2.className = "ico i-easy";
    div3.appendChild(iElement2);
    link3 = document.createElement("a");
    link3.href = "#";
    t3 = document.createTextNode("easy");
    link3.appendChild(t3);
    div3.appendChild(link3);

    /* <div class="likes"><i class="ico i-likes"></i><a href="#">10</a></div> */
    div4 = document.createElement("div");
    div4.className="likes";
    div2.appendChild(div4);
    iElement3 = document.createElement("i");
    iElement3.className = "ico i-likes";
    div4.appendChild(iElement3);
    link4 = document.createElement("a");
    link4.href = "#";
    t4 = document.createTextNode("10");
    link4.appendChild(t4);
    div4.appendChild(link4);

    /* <div class="comments"><i class="ico i-comments"></i><a href="recipe.html#comments">27</a></div> */
    div5 = document.createElement("div");
    div5.className="comments";
    div2.appendChild(div5);
    iElement4 = document.createElement("i");
    iElement4.className = "ico i-comments";
    div5.appendChild(iElement4);
    link5 = document.createElement("a");
    link5.href = "#";
    t5 = document.createTextNode("27");
    link5.appendChild(t5);
    div5.appendChild(link5);
    /*
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    */
}

//Masonry Code
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
    $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
}); 
});
});
```

The end result of the photos look like this
http://i58.tinypic.com/xbcv1w.png

Comment: Would you be able to pare-down your example to the bare minimum to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hi. Sorry it's very hard to since I retrieve my images from a database and create a container for every one of them. I am not sure on how to make a simpler replication of my problem.

Comment: Are you loading imagesloaded.js? Without an example it is very hard to answer with an image showing your issue. At least pass on any errors seen in the Developer console.

Comment: Hi. The funny thing is that there are no errors at all in the Developer console. I have loaded imagesloaded.js and I figured it must have been the way I tried to implement javascript masonry. Is there a different way to apply javascript masonry if I am adding elements dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically loaded items, you can call masonry and then reload items and then layout:

```
//Masonry Code
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
$grid.masonry({
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true,
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
});
$grid.masonry( 'reloadItems' );
$grid.masonry('layout'); 
});
```

Comment: I tried this and the same result displayed. For some reason, my grid height is 0 which is why i think the items are all overlapping in one column spot. Is there a css attribute I'm supposed to apply to the grid? Sorry for not having an example for you to replicate.

Comment: Try a simple test in css `.grid{height:100%;}`

Comment: Try setting {{overflow:auto}} on the container/parent.

Comment: Hi. It was a problem on my end. I have tabs on the page which displays the content as hidden. Therefore, the grid size was always 0 until I resized the page. I just added a trigger to load the images when the tab was pressed and it worked. Thanks for the help!